# App Engine logging: too may log statements per request - how to get at the log data?

Tags: google-app-engine

Our application does some relatively complex stuff, resulting in each request generating somewhere between 50 to a few thousand lines of log statements.

We're recently crossed a threshold - the Web console simply cuts off the request log data beyond a certain point.  This wouldn't be so much of an issue, except that downloading the log contents has the same problem.

(clarification) the logs display the log data for every request, but don't display it completely.  We can see that requests A B C were processed, but the log details for A and C is cut off beyond a certain point.

We're paying for the extra log space.

Any ideas on how to get at the complete log data dump?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Engine actually stops recording logs for a request after a certain point. The only way to get at your logs is to log less, so you can still find the important stuff.

Comment: Does this also apply to backends?, I mean, backends are supposed to run for long times. I'm seeing that only the last 1000 log entries are being logged. Where can we find info about the limitations of the logging module and workarounds?